# PowerShell: автоматизация ввода

Tags: powershell

День добрый,

У меня имеется `PowerShell` скрипт который при запуске удаляет папку. Но дело в том что при его запуске скрипт спрашивает у меня подтверждения вводом буквы Y. Скажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы скрипт сам себе водил букву Y то есть не просил ввода?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Remove-Item <path> -recurse -force
```